# einsetzen in + Dat./Akk

Tags: grammatical-case

Im Buch, das ich derzeit lese (  »Der nasse Fisch« von Volker Kutscher), wird der Hauptcharakter von einem Dezernat der Berliner Polizei in ein anderes versetzt.  Da sagt ihm sein zukünftiger Chef :

- > »Nun, Herr Rath, hier bei uns werden Sie erst einmal in einer bereits eingearbeiteten Truppe eingesetzt…«

Ich hätte eigentlich den Akkusativ erwartet, also *in eine (…) Truppe   eingesetzt*.  Ist der Wen-Fall gar möglich in diesem Satz und, wenn ja, gibt es Bedeutungsunterschiede zwischen den beiden Fällen?

Comment: In + Dativ kann mit so ziemlich jedem Verb verwendet werden, bei dem eine Ortsangabe Sinn macht. In + Akkusativ geht nur dann, wenn eine Angabe des Ziels oder der Richtung möglich ist. Das ist bei *einsetzen* zwar möglich, aber in Bezug auf Personen klingt es merkwürdig, da stimme ich der Antwort von The Awful Language zu.

Answer (score 6):

> Nun, Herr Rath, hier bei uns werden Sie erst einmal in eine bereits eingearbeitete Truppe eingesetzt…

Das ist möglich (im Prinzip) und die Bedeutung ändert sich. In diesem Fall klänge es, als würde Herr Rath *platziert* (wie in einen Steckkasten). (Mit Bezug auf eine "Truppe" klingt es allerdings sehr seltsam. Da dürfte "Truppe" nicht wortwörtlich, sondern nur als Name verwendet werden.)

Es würde dann in diesen Bedeutungen verwendet:

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einsetzen)

> 1. a) [als Teil] in etwas setzen, hineinbringen, einfügen, einarbeiten

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einsetzen)

> 3 *[transitiv](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/transitiv)*: ein Teil passend zu einem Ganzen hinzufügen; Pflanzen auf einem Areal eingraben; Fische in ein Gewässer, Wild in ein Revier einbringen

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/einsetzen)

> 1) etw. in etw. hineinsetzen, einarbeiten
>
> 8) etw. einlegen, zusätzlich einfügen

Gemeint ist hingegen

> 9) etw., jmdn. verwenden, gebrauchen

Siehe Beispielsatz

> er war zum Räumen, bei der Polizei eingesetzt worden

Das Problem ist auch das *in*. Wenn man jemanden z. B. in ein Amt einsetzt (also "Truppe" als Wort für ein Amt wie Richter), wird es mit *als* gebildet (*Herr Rath wurde als Richter eingesetzt*. Wenn mit *in*, dann eher umbauen: *Herr Rath wurde in das Richteramt eingesetzt*.)

Zum [Dativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ)

> Sein Name rührt daher, dass eine typische Funktion des Dativs ist, den Empfänger des Gegebenen zu bezeichnen.

[Dativ bei Präposition](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#Dativ_bei_Pr%C3%A4positionen) (Hervorhebung durch Fettdruck von mir)

> Präpositionen, die immer den Dativ nach sich ziehen, sind: *aus*, *außer*, ***bei***, *entgegen*, *entsprechend*, *gegenüber*, *gemäß*, *mit*, *nach*, *nahe*, *nebst*, *samt*, *seit*, *von*, *zu*, *zufolge* und einige andere..
>
> Bei einigen Präpositionen des Ortes können sowohl Dativ als auch [Akkusativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkusativ) stehen. Der Dativ gibt den aktuellen Ort an (*wo?*), während der Akkusativ die Richtung auf ein Ziel bezeichnet (*wohin?*). So verhält es sich mit *in* (Beispiel: „wir schlafen in *dem* Bett“, „wir gehen in *das* Bett“). Diese Wechselpräpositionen, bei denen entweder Dativ oder Akkusativ stehen kann, sind: ***in***, *an*, *auf*, *vor*, *hinter*, *über*, *unter*, *neben*, *zwischen*.

Frage: **Wo** wird Herr Rath eingesetzt?

Ein weiterer Hinweis ist, dass man den Satz auch mit *bei* konstruieren kann:

> Nun, Herr Rath, hier bei uns werden Sie erst einmal bei einer bereits eingearbeiteten Truppe eingesetzt…

Ich nehme an, dass das *in* gewählt wurde, damit nicht zweimal kurz nacheinander *bei* Verwendung findet.

Answer (score 5):

Es geht darum, *wo* Herr Rath eingesetzt wird, nicht *wohin*. Herr Rath soll in dieser Gruppe arbeiten.
Wohin im Zusammenhang mit Einsetzen würde man fragen, wenn es darum geht, dass ein Bauteil an einen bestimmten Ort eingesetzt, also platziert wird.